# How to get html span value to C# variable

Tags: c#, html

I am working on web application. in my html page I have a code like this:

```
<tr>
    <td class="style1">
        <span>Sex:&nbsp;</span>
    </td>
    <td class="style1">
        <span id="Sex_PDLabel"><b>--</b></span> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

this sex value I want to access in my C# code..

how I can write code for that..

in my code page I try to add code like this:

string text = Sex_PDLabel.InnerText; this time this id(Sex_PDLabel) is not coming..how I can get that value in my code page.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372637/span-value-not-showing-in-text-box-in-web-application/

Answer (score 0):

You can get this by using the `InnerText` property:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string text = Sex_PDLabel.InnerText;

   //text => "--"
}
```

`InnerText` is used to just get the text content, ignoring any HTML. Alternatively, if you wanted the HTML, use the `.InnerHTML` property.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string htmlText = Sex_PDLabel.InnerHTML;

   //text => "<b>--</b>"
}
```

Comment: i mean my span id is not getting in page load part

Comment: Add a `<span runat="server"/>` attribute to see it server-side.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Add the following attributes to your span tags

id="sp_male" runat="server"

id="Sex_PDLabel" runat="server"

.cs file

string value = sp_male.InnerText;

string value1 = Sex_PDLabel.InnerText;